# URL Redirect map is not working when i use the language in the OLD URL path

Tags: sxa, redirect, seo, url-rewrite, settings

In the Sitecore 8.2:

I'm trying to redirect the OLD URL to the NEW URL. Using the Redirect MAP 301.
[image: Redirect MAP]

When I use language code in the OLD URL the redirection is not working. It's resolved to 404. other than that everything is fine.

For example:

**OLD URL**: /fr/article/landing => **New URL**: /landing

**OLD URL**: /fr-ch/article/landing = > **New URL**: /landing

The above scenario is not working. If I remove the language code from the URL the redirection is working well. But I want a few OLD URLs with these language codes to redirect. Please suggest.

Additional information:

The below scenarios are working fine.

OLD URL: /article/landing page => New URL: /fr-ch/artcile/new landing

OLD URL: /fr-ch/landing page => New URL:/fr-ch/artcile/new landing

OLD URL: /fr-ch/landing page => New URL:/artcile/new landing

While using a different language in the OLD URL it's not working. For example, if I work for the fr-ch language site. And I'm trying to do the redirect as mentioned below. And the below scenario is not working.

OLD URL: /fr/landing page => New URL:/fr-ch/artcile/new landing

Comment: Does the old URL actually need to be a regular expression?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be a regular expression

Comment: resolved to 404 with the old URL or with the new URL in the browser? could you please try and add the language code in the new URL as well?

Comment: Hi @MahendraShekhawat Resolved 404 with the old URL in the browser.

The below scenarios are working fine. 

OLD URL: /article/landing page => New URL: /fr-ch/artcile/new landing

OLD URL: /fr-ch/landing page => New URL:/fr-ch/artcile/new landing

OLD URL: /fr-ch/landing page => New URL:/artcile/new landing

When using a different language in the OLD URL it is not working. 
For example, if i work for the fr-ch language site. And im trying to do the redirect as mentioned below. And the below scenario is not working.

OLD URL: /fr/landing page => New URL:/fr-ch/artcile/new landing